# Rspec controller spec doesn't fail with missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm testing a Rails (5.2.2.1) project using Rspec (rspec-rails 3.8.2) and rails-controller-testing (1.0.4).
I have a controller that looks like this:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

And a controller spec that looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ThingsController do
  it 'renders a template' do
    get :new, xhr: true, format: :js
    expect(response).to render_template :new
  end
end
```

I've created an html template in `app/views/things/new.html.erb` but no .js template. The spec passes even without the appropriate template. Shouldn't the spec fail? How would I write the spec so that it fails without the .js template?

Answer (score 1):

controller specs does not render views by default, you can call `render_views` to make it render them

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ThingsController do
  render_views
  it 'renders a template' do
    get :new, xhr: true, format: :js
    expect(response).to render_template :new
  end
end
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/docs/controller-specs/render-views

EDIT: the reason for the controller NOT rendering the views by default is that you can add a proper View spec to test that the view exists and has the content you want

Comment: Even with render_views, it doesn't fail - it just renders the html template instead of trying (and failing) to render a .js template